# Database and Application Server Speed Issue

Tags: sql

I have a System which has application server and database server.

In the initial stage, both Database and Application Servers run in a same Physical Server. After that we have segregated these two servers in to separate segments in the network. i.e We have defined two separate VLAN s as application and database and put these two servers in to these two different vlans and given the required access permission through the firewall.

After the segregation we had a major issue regarding the slowness between application and db servers. We have checked the network connectivity and we couldn't find any issue from the network side for the slowness.

After that we have put both Application and DB servers in to one server like the implementation stage. Then the slowness issue has rectified.

I want to know what could be happen for this slowness.

Please advice me.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Achala, welcome to Stack Overflow. http://serverfault.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be able to provide you with a better answer sooner.